# What do alchemy and infura actually do?

Tags: alchemy

I deployed a contract via (?) alchemy, then deleted the alchemy app. The contract still works,
on etherscan, as it did before — even for writes. This is encouraging, but begs the question: for which part of the deployment is alchemy actually necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Alchemy and Infura are RPC Node providers. To communicate with the blockchain, you need a node. But since it requires a significant setup, platforms like alchemy and infura provide access to the node as a service. When you deeply a contract using Infura, it just means that the transaction was broadcast to other nodes via Infura. Once the transaction is minted, the contract stays in the blockchain. Now even if you delete the app in infura, the contract will continue to live on the blockchain.